# Get Instagram feed with Curl

Tags: php, json, curl, instagram

I'm trying to get Instagram pictures with the Instagram API. This is my code that i use:

```
    $url = "https://www.instagram.com/'.$username.'/?__a=1";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $insta = json_decode($result, true);

    $instagram_photos = $insta["graphql"]["user"]["edge_owner_to_timeline_media"]["edges"];
    $user = $insta["graphql"]["user"]["username"];
    $name = $insta["graphql"]["user"]["full_name"];
    $bio = $insta["graphql"]["user"]["biography"];
    $profilepic = $insta["graphql"]["user"]["profile_pic_url_hd"];
```

On my Mamp the pictures and data from the url shows, but on my production site no data will show. When i var_dump the $result variable, there shows an empty string "". When i var_dump the $url variable, the Instagram shows correctly with the username.

Answer (score 0):

This seems wrong:

```
$url = "https://www.instagram.com/'.$username.'/?__a=1";
```

Try this:

```
$url = "https://www.instagram.com/{$username}/?__a=1";
```

It is very possible that Instagram is blocking such requests via curl/cli/php, or it would Forward your request to the Login page..

Also in your PHP curl request you do not do any sanity checks.. like, for example what does Curl returns as HTTP code:

```
"Curl returned: ".curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```

check [curl_getinfo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php)

You also do not check if JSON did not error out via [json_last_error](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php)
. Those are basics in troubleshooting..

Once you know what each of those returns, you will be able to better troubleshoot your code.

Comment: No result, the variable $result is empty

Comment: What do you get if you run: `echo file_get_contents("https://www.instagram.com/{$username}/?__a=1");` ?

Comment: Also from your production server, via CLI, what HTTP code do you get if you run: `curl -i "https://www.instagram.com/_your_username_here_/?__a=1"` and adding your username as a test ?

Comment: With file_get_contents i get the login page from Instagram, what only shows the icon from Instagram.

Comment: The curl returned: 0 and the json_last_error gives an int(4)

Comment: You seem to want us to just fix the error in your code. I believe I've provided few different guidelines, which will help you learn to troubleshoot your code, but for that there has to be will and effort from your end :) SO is not a: `we will fix it for you` service